# Sharepoint 2013 - Radio button default check is not working not even script is working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I tried all options like Checked, Checked = true/false etc but non works in SP2013.

```js
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  var input = document.getElementById('section1');
  input.select();
}
</script>
```

```html
<input name="sections" id="option1" type="radio"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have the wrong ID for the radio button, the id of this radio is `option1`. The first step should be to get that element and then change the status of `checked`. Here's the snippet that could help you.

please try :

```
var input = document.getElementById("option1");
input.checked=true;
```